# plotly express heatmap cell size

Tags: python, plotly

How can i change the size of cells in a plotly express heatmap? I would need bigger cells

```
import plotly.express as px
fig1 = px.imshow(df[col],color_continuous_scale='Greens')
fig1.layout.yaxis.type = 'category'
fig1.layout.xaxis.type = 'category'
fig1.layout.yaxis.tickmode = 'linear'
fig1.layout.xaxis.tickmode = 'linear'
fig1.layout.xaxis.tickangle = 65
fig1.layout.autosize = True
fig1.layout.height = 500
fig1.layout.width = 500

fig1.show()
```

**Result (very narrow)**

[image]

Comment: Can you please attach your dataframe or a sample dataframe similar to yours? Otherwise no one can reproduce your code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

'px' may not make it square due to the color bar, so why not use 'go'?

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Heatmap(
                    z=[[1, 20, 30],
                      [20, 1, 60],
                      [30, 60, 1]]))

fig.show()
```

[image]

Set the graph size.

```
fig.layout.height = 500
fig.layout.width = 500
```

[image]

Examples at px

```
import plotly.express as px
data=[[1, 25, 30, 50, 1], [20, 1, 60, 80, 30], [30, 60, 1, 5, 20]]
fig = px.imshow(data,
                labels=dict(x="Day of Week", y="Time of Day", color="Productivity"),
                x=['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'],
                y=['Morning', 'Afternoon', 'Evening']
               )
fig.update_xaxes(side="top")

fig.layout.height = 500
fig.layout.width = 500

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The cells are square, but plotly really lacks a way to set a cell width. Since we can only configure the graph width, the cell size varies according to the numer of cells. And since the graph width seems to include tick texts, legens, etc. one can't just set the width as a multiple of the number of cells.

Comment: Actually, your second example does not really have square cells. The total size is 336x320 in pixel dimensions.

Answer (score 5):

A little late, but if you want the cells to be wider, use this:

```py
fig1 = px.imshow(df[col],color_continuous_scale='Greens', aspect='auto')
```

Setting the aspect argument to "auto" will fill the plotting area using non-square tiles.